# Remove duplicate tuples from list of lists using python

Tags: python, tuples, nested-lists

I have a list of a list of tuples, like the toy example below. I am trying to remove the nested lists that have duplicate tuples from my bigger list. For example, the first two nested lists contain duplicate tuples (e.g., `('A',1)` `('B',2)` etc).

```
[[('A', 1),
  ('B', 2),
  ('C', 3),
  ('D', 4),
  ('E', 5),
  ('F', 6),
  ('G', 7),
  ('H', 8)],
 [('A', 1),
  ('B', 2),
  ('C', 3),
  ('D', 4),
  ('E', 5),
  ('F', 6),
  ('H', 7),
  ('G', 8)], 
[('G', 1),
 ('H', 2),
 ('F', 3),
 ('E', 4),
 ('D', 5),
 ('C', 6),
 ('B', 7),
 ('A', 8)]]
```

Desired output, where each list contains unique tuples:

```
[[('A', 1),
  ('B', 2),
  ('C', 3),
  ('D', 4),
  ('E', 5),
  ('F', 6),
  ('G', 7),
  ('H', 8)],
[('G', 1),
 ('H', 2),
 ('F', 3),
 ('E', 4),
 ('D', 5),
 ('C', 6),
 ('B', 7),
 ('A', 8)]]
```

Comment: What is `bigger list`?

Comment: I mean the brackets containing the nested lists. So each tuple contained in a nested list and then that nested list contained in a list itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: Nop, you'll have to rephrase the question

Comment: Lemme try again: In my toy example, it's a list that contains 3 _nested_ lists. So my list is equivalent to [X, Y, Z] where X = `[('A', 1),('B', 2),('C', 3),('D', 4),('E', 5),('F', 6),('G', 7),('H', 8)]`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: where is `H,7` in your output? or `G,8`

Comment: Expected output seems incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to reshape the data and drop duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd

x  = [
    [('A', 1),  ('B', 2),  ('C', 3),  ('D', 4),  ('E', 5),  ('F', 6),  ('G', 7),  ('H', 8)],
    [('A', 1),  ('B', 2),  ('C', 3),  ('D', 4),  ('E', 5),  ('F', 6),  ('H', 7),  ('G', 8)], 
    [('G', 1), ('H', 2), ('F', 3), ('E', 4), ('D', 5), ('C', 6), ('B', 7), ('A', 8)]
]

output = (
    pd.DataFrame(x)
      .T
      .melt()
      .drop_duplicates(subset='value')
      .groupby('variable')['value']
      .apply(list).to_list()
)

print(output)
```

Output

```
[
    [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('F', 6), ('G', 7), ('H', 8)], 
    [('H', 7), ('G', 8)], 
    [('G', 1), ('H', 2), ('F', 3), ('E', 4), ('D', 5), ('C', 6), ('B', 7), ('A', 8)]
]
```

Comment: OP doesn't use pandas

Comment: @TheSingularity Maybe he should :)